# Java Polymorphism Test on Hackerrank failing for specific test cases, works fine for all others

Tags: java, polymorphism, primes

I'm trying to write a program that can find the list of prime numbers and the list of happy numbers in between a start and end element. It seems to work for the most part, but there are 2 specific test cases where it won't pass for some reason, despite passing all the others. I included the code below.

It works by taking one number, which it makes a startElement, and then another number, an endElement. It then proceeds to return 2 strings, one containing a list of all prime numbers in between those two numbers, if there are any, and one containing a list of all happy numbers in between these two numbers, if there are any.

A happy number is when the sum of the squares of each digit in a number eventually comes down to 1. For example 28.

```
2^2 + 8^2 = 68
6^2 + 8^2 = 100
1^2 + 0 + 0 = 1
```

If this process makes the number equal 4 eventually, it isn't a happy number.

````
```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    
    
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
        
        int a, b;
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        b = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        
        ChildOne childOne = new ChildOne(a, b);
        ChildTwo childTwo = new ChildTwo(a, b);
        
        //System.out.println(a);
        //System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(childOne.filter());
        System.out.println(childTwo.filter());
    }
}

class Parent{
    public int startElement;
    public int endElement;
    
    String filter(){
        return null;
    }
}

class ChildOne extends Parent{
    
    ChildOne(int a, int b){
        this.startElement = a;
        this.endElement = b;
    }
    
    public boolean isPrime(int num){
        
        if(num == 1)
            return false;
            
        for(int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++){
            if(num % i == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    String filter(){
        String result = "";
        
        for(int i = startElement; i <= endElement; i++){
            if(isPrime(i)){
                result += (" " + i);
            }
        }
        
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            return result;
        }
        
        return result.substring(1);
    }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent{
    
    ChildTwo(int a, int b){
        this.startElement = a;
        this.endElement = b;
    }
    
    public boolean isHappy(int num){
        int check = squareSum(num);
        
        while(true){
            check = squareSum(check);
            
            //System.out.println(check);
            
            if(check == 1)
                return true;
            else if(check == 4)
                return false;
        }
    }
    
    public int squareSum(int num){
        // Gets the individual digits of the number
        char[] digits = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
        
        int result = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){
            result += (Character.getNumericValue(digits[i]) * Character.getNumericValue((int)digits[i]));
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    String filter(){
        String result = "";
        
        for(int i = startElement; i < endElement; i++){
            if(isHappy(i)){
                result += (" " + i);
            }
        }
        
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            return result;
        }
        
        return result.substring(1);
    }
}
```
````

The 2 test cases where it fails are the following sets of startElement and endElement

```
1, 5555
and
623, 3456
```

For the record, the program does run just fine with these two test cases, as far as I can tell, but the site still says it failed, and I have no idea why, as it won't tell me what the output is supposed to be.

Anybody have any idea why these two test cases are failing while all others seem to pass?

Answer (score 0):

hope you already got the solution.
here is the issue
in ChildTwo the condition should be i <= endElement